# Can't remove all Boolean == false in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean, splice

Given an array with different data types. I write a function to find those values which are `false` and return the array without the `falsy` values.

For example:

```
[7, "ate", "", false, 9] should return [7, "ate", 9].
```

This is my current code:

```
function bouncer(arr)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if (Boolean(arr[i]) == false)
        {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
     }
     console.log(arr);
}
```

However, there is a problem:

**I.)**

```
In case of Input: bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9])
It returns: [ 7, 'ate', false, 9 ]
But it should return: [7, "ate", 9]
```

**II.)**

```
In case of input: `bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]);`
It returns: [ null, NaN, '' ]
But it should return: []
```

I don't understand why it returns the boolean false values like `NaN` or `null`. But it correctly splices off values like empty strings (`""`) or `undefined`.

And I also don't understand, why in the first case it returns `false` (which is not intended), but in the second case it does not returns `false`.

Thank you very much for clarification.

Comment: JavaScript has the concept of "falsy", so use `===` instead of `==`. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: Don't change the array you're iterating over, unless you know what you're doing ;) Check the elements on each step. (Hint: What's happening with the elements after the element that gets removed?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other people says, you can use `filter()` for this purpose. The shortest way would be:

```js
const array = [false, null, true, 0, NaN, undefined, "", "Hola Mundo"];
console.log(array.filter(Boolean));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

However, getting back to your code, you should note that `splice()` method will change the array when it detect a `falsy` value (because removes one element). In other words, the `arr.length` is decreasing dinamically while the loop executes, but the `i` variable keeps incrementing. This generates that the loop actually won't loop all the elements on the array. To fix this, you have to decrement the value of the variable `i` when you are removing an element from the array. Check next code:

```js
function bouncer(arr)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if (Boolean(arr[i]) === false)
        {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
            i = i - 1;
        }
    }

    console.log(arr);
}

bouncer([false, null, true, 0, NaN, undefined, "", "Hola Mundo"]);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost done, but it would be better to check what values are falsy instead to compare them, so this function will do the trick

```
const getNonFalsyValues = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((arr, current) => {
    if (Boolean(current)) {
        arr.push(current);
    }
    return arr;
  }, []);
}
```

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like this.

What filter does here is it add value in the output array only if it is true.

```js
let arr = [false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, "", 1 , 123];
let op = arr.filter(value => value);
console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const bouncer = (arr) => arr.filter(val => !!val);
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript some values evaluate to `false`, like `null`, empty string `''` and `undefined`. You can check more about evaluation in JavaScript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description).

Also you should use `===` instead of `==` in comparisons. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons).